# Checking if a facebook profile is verified or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, koala-gem

I am developing an app in which I want to know if a facebook authorized user has a verified profile or not. I can see that [there](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user) is a `is_verified` field that facebook provides. I am just not getting it in the response I get from OAuth. Is there any permissions issue? I am using permissions `public_profile,email`. Please guide me on this.

Comment: Please include the code you're using, what it's doing, and what you want/expect it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask 'is_verified' field in your query. You can try below code as a sample and u can take the appropriate part of the code to integrate in yours. public_profile,email permission is enough to get this field. result will be a bolean

```
$fb_page = 'barackobama'; //any fb page,fb profile
$access_token = ''; //your access token
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/".$fb_page.'
?access_token='.$access_token.'&fields=is_verified';
$curl = curl_init($url);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
$result = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);  
$details = json_decode($result,true);
echo "verified:".$details['is_verified'];
```